# Quartz next fire time to human readable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, quartz-scheduler

I persisted the quartz jobs with MySQL.

The column `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` and `PREV_FIRE_TIME` is hard to determine the time.

Could someone provide a MySQL select syntax for easy track the time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should put this as the answer so it can be accepted :) I'll upvote it

Answer (score 3):

It's linke an epoch in ms, so divide by 1000 before converting with `TO_UNIXTIME`:

```
select 
    qt.job_group, 
    qt.job_name, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(qt.start_time / 1000) AS startTime, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(qt.prev_fire_time / 1000) AS prevFireTime, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(qt.next_fire_time / 1000) AS nextFireTime, 
    SEC_TO_TIME((qt.next_fire_time - qt.prev_fire_time) / 1000) AS diff, 
    (qst.REPEAT_INTERVAL / 1000) AS repeatIntervalInSecs, 
    qst.TIMES_TRIGGERED AS timesTriggered 
from 
    QRTZ_TRIGGERS AS qt 
    LEFT JOIN QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS AS qst 
    ON qt.TRIGGER_NAME = qst.TRIGGER_NAME;`
```